# Long roles have a Goldilocks problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

Pictures being worth 1,000 words, here's [a teams page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/5) as rendered by:

#### Chrome (46.0.2490.86 m)

[image]

#### Internet Explorer (11.0.9600.18015CO)

[image]

For what it's worth, my idea of "just right" would be just adding a tooltip on hover to the former version. Too much dead space in the neighboring boxes of the latter for my tastes.

Comment: That is one magnificent whale.

Comment: Freehand circles are out. Freehand whales are the future!

Comment: As someone that frequently browses SE on a tablet I'd like to see them getting away from using tooltips.

Comment: I'm upvoting mainly because of the whale… :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

We now limit the number of characters shown and require users to use a shorter title (40 characters — we used the data from existing Teams to choose that number).